# Definite integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \frac{e^{-ix^2}}{x+a}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to evaluate the integral
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \frac{e^{-ix^2}}{x+a}
=\lim_{\substack{\varepsilon\to 0\\ R\to +\infty}}
\left[\int_{-R}^{-a-\varepsilon}+\int_{-a+\varepsilon}^{R}\right]
dx \frac{e^{-ix^2}}{x+a},
\end{equation}
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

I know that
\begin{equation}
I = \mathrm{sgn}(a)i\pi e^{-ia^2} + e^{i\pi/4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x+ae^{i\pi/4}}.
\end{equation}
But I can't evaluate the integral in the last term either. Does the integral converge?

Comment: As written, the integral is meaningless. If $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $\frac{e^{-ix^2}}{x+a}$ is neither improperly-Riemann or Lebesgue integrable over the real line. If you are looking for a (Cauchy) principal value, you should state it.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You are right. Actually I want the integral from -R to -a-ε plus -a+ε to R, when ε limited to 0+ and R limited to +∞.

Answer (score 0):

We want to compute
$$ \lim_{\substack{\varepsilon\to 0\\ R\to +\infty}}\left[\int_{-a+\varepsilon}^{R}+\int_{-R}^{-a-\varepsilon}\right]\frac{e^{-ix^2}}{x+a}\,dx = \lim_{\substack{\varepsilon\to 0\\ R\to +\infty}}\left[\int_{\varepsilon}^{R+a}+\int_{-R+a}^{-\varepsilon}\right]\frac{e^{-i(x-a)^2}}{x}\,dx$$
where both $\int_{R}^{R+a}$ and $\int_{-R-a}^{-R}$ are bounded by $O\left(\frac{1}{R}\right)$ in absolute value. So the problem is equivalent to computing
$$\text{PV}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-i(x-a)^2}\frac{dx}{x} =\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-i(x-a)^2}-e^{-i(x+a)^2}}{x}\,dx\tag{A}$$
or
$$2i e^{-ia^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2ax)e^{-ix^2}}{x}\,dx $$
which in terms of [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) equals
$$ \pi (i-1) e^{-ia^2}\left[S\left(a\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}\right)-i\,C\left(a\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}\right)\right].\tag{B} $$

Comment: Would you please give some more details about the last step. I know nothing about Fresnel integrals other than the definition.